# App/program that I can share pdf notes across android and windows?

Tags: pdf

I read a lot of pdfs for study and I write notes for them. I read my pdfs on a tablet and I currently write notes with Moon Reader. But I can't export the notes and highlights from Android to Windows/Linux. What program(s)/app(s) can I use to be able to export/import notes?

Comment: What do you mean by "export"? Moon+ stores highlights and annotations as a separate layer inside the PDF as well as in a separate text file which you simply can copy. So what do you miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xodo](http://www.xodo.com/) is completely free, and available on Android/iOS/Windows Desktop/Windows Mobile. You can share a document with your self, and it will be available on all devices, and even in a web browser (no installation required).

There is no import/export, because there is no need when sharing.

To get started sharing see Xodo Connect option here.
http://feedback.xodo.com/knowledgebase/articles/614835-getting-started-xodo-basics

Comment: Am I able to search through my notes?

Comment: Yes, you can search annotations/notes/comments